# Wiretapping requests to VPN providers

Tags: vpn, logging, international

What are valid issuers of wiretapping requests aimed at VPN providers except the court of the provider's country?

Is it possible that country in which jurisdiction VPN provider does not act will issue a wiretapping request which will cause user being wiretapped?

Added:
For example: I am interested in using VPN of Netherlands and in whether Russia can issue a wiretapping request for VPN provider in Netherlands. What should be my way of research?

In simple words: will Netherlands wiretap me for Russia?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're asking.  I think you're asking that if you are using a VPN hosted in say, the US, can the US government wiretap and read communication?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It depends a bit on the VPN provider too. Some will only respond to a court order, while others will hand over data much more freely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some countries have reciprocal agreements for wiretapping; others may tap parts of the route if it crosses their border.

Realistically, wiretaps are most likely to monitor one of 3 points: the client, the provider, the server - depending on the threat being responded to.

If you are being monitored and are in a country with a reciprocal agreement with the country hosting the VPN then you could be tapped at 2 or more points.

There is no single answer to this question, unfortunately, other than 'yes - it is possible'

Comment: In particular I am interested in using VPN of Netherlands and in whether Russia can issue a wiretapping request for VPN provider in Netherlands. What should be my way of research?